# Loose phrasing in Spivak's Calculus?

Tags: calculus

At the start of Chapter 19 in Spivak's Calculus (4ed), he remarks that "Every computation of a derivative yields, according to the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus [I give this below], a formula about integrals". I'm not convinced that this statement is fair. In particular, it seems to suggest that every function which is a derivative of some function is also integrable, but of course [this is not true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function). Am I missing something here?

> Second FTC: If $f$ is (Riemann) integrable on $[a,b]$ and $f = g'$ for some function $g$ then $\int_a^bf = g(b)-g(a)$.

Comment: I think it is loose phrasing, as you suggest.

Comment: Noted @littleO. I should mention that I added the "Riemann" bit in the statement of FTC. Does that change things?

Comment: No, I still think it’s loose phrasing, for the reason you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't say that every function which is a derivative of some function is also integrable. It says: **if** $f$ is Riemann integrable and $f = g'$ ...

Comment: If you meant the informal statement in your initial quote, then sure. I thought you meant the statement of second FTC.

Comment: No, sorry, I mean the informal statement at the start of the question.